# extjs close event doesn't fire

Tags: javascript, events, extjs, view

I have this code in the init function of my controller:

```
this.control({
   'import_view': { close: this.closeImportView }
});
```

where 'import_view' is a selector of my view that is a part of tabpanel.
When I press Close tab nothing happens and event doesn't fire. I checked all aliases and other syntax mistakes but found nothing. Who knows why this event may not firing?

Comment: Are you using version 5.x ?

Comment: @FrancisDucharme no, I have 4.2.1

Comment: Try adding a pound (#) sign, like `#import_view`

Comment: @FrancisDucharme still doesn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: I also have second close event in this controller and it is attached to the another view, but it works. so it is very strange..

Comment: make sure your controller config options have: `views: ['ViewA', 'ViewB']` meaning it will control both these views.

Comment: also, I'm not sure you are listening to the correct event. You say you have a tab in a tabpanel with a "Close" label ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that I had two different events attached to my view in this way:

```
'evt_import_view': { close: this.closeImportView }, 
'evt_import_view': { render: this.onCloudInitialized }
```

and this is not correct.
The correct way not to have error with close event is to write in this way:

```
'evt_import_view': { close: this.closeImportView, render: this.onCloudInitialized }
```